# C + + Error: statement cannot resolve address of overloaded function

Tags: c++, function, variables

I am trying to make a game in C++. My editor is Code::Blocks and my compiler is MinGW. The game is a text-based survival game with the variables hunger, thirst, warmth, and choice. When i try to tell the player the values of hunger, thirst, and warmth, it gives me the error that the title of this question states. I am a relatively new programmer, but i understand the basics. I will now print the code i used:

```
cout<< "Your hunger is"; hunger;  endl;
cout<< "Your warmth is"; warmth;  endl;
cout<< "Your thirst is"; thirst;  endl;
```

This is where the variables get changed (this is one example):

```
int wood()
{
cout<< "You have chosen find firewood!"<< endl;
if ((rand() % 2) == 2){
    cout<< "You found firewood!"<<endl;
    warmth = warmth + 1;
}
else{
    cout<< "You could not find any firewood"<< endl;
}
}
```

In the same function that i tell the player the code, they are supposed to lose one point in each variable per turn:

```
warmth = warmth - 1;
hunger = hunger - 1;
thirst = thirst - 1;
```

The code is over 100 lines long, so i wont paste the entirety of the code unless asked. If any of the variables get to 0, the game ends:

```
if (hunger = 0){
    cout<< "You starved!"<< endl;
    cout<< "Game over!"<< endl;
    return 0;
}
if (thirst = 0){
    cout<< "You became dehydrated!"<< endl;
    cout<< "Game over!"<< endl;
    return 0;
}
if (warmth = 0){
    cout<< "You froze!"<< endl;
    cout<< "Game over!"<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Btw when you get compilation error it points to particular line, you should at least paste exact message comiler gives you and line where it points to.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
cout<< "Your hunger is" << hunger <<  endl;
```

and so on

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple typos in you code.  When you do

```
cout<< "Your hunger is"; hunger;  endl;
```

You have 3 statements instead of one output statement.  You nned to have

```
cout << "Your hunger is" << hunger << endl;
```

Which chains it all together.  Otherwise it trys to call `endl()` but it can't since there is no associated stream object.

You also have an issue with all of you if statements.

```
if (hunger = 0)
```

Will always be false as you are evaluating the result of setting `hunger` to `0` which is `0`.  You need to change all of the uses `=` in your if's to `==` to do an equals comparison.